# "Camera cancelled" error in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, camera

Iam trying take a picture using camera and store the path of the image in database. I have written the code for taking picture using camera.The camera opens and then shows an error message as camera cancelled .
This is my js code  :

```
.controller('cameractrl', function($scope, Myfactory,$window,$cordovaSQLite) 
         {
   alert("cameractrl");
   $scope.capturePhoto=function() 
   {                                                          
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        sourceType :Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, });
  }

     function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
        alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath);

  }
```

And i have added the following permission in AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

and in config.xml i have added this:

```
  <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
```

But still the camera is opening? and then it closes with the alert Camera Cancelled.
any solutions???

Here is my config.xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <widget id="com.ionicframework.starter" version="0.0.1"       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.ionic.keyboard.IonicKeyboard" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="AdMob">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.AdMob" />
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
<name>HelloCordova</name>
<description>
    An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
  Ionic Framework Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external" />
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
```

Comment: try run cordova plugin, what you see?

Comment: yes i tried cordova plugin but then also the camera is not opening

Comment: what you saw my friend, please state it here.

Comment: i saw a page with the button capture photo. And when i click on that nothing happens.Iam runing it on android emulator.

Comment: which Phonegap version you are working, do you add CameraLauncher.java in you code ?

Comment: i have added the cordova camera plugin via cmd

Comment: do you add this line "<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />"  By your way or , when install plugin it will be added ?   if possible do you please show full config.xml

Comment: k i posted the config.xml

Comment: remove this line "<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" /> see you have already added when you installed plugin. Search CameraLauncher, there two time

Comment: no its not working, in console an error is shown as Camera.js : Uncaught Reference Error require is not defined

Comment: do you add Camera.js in you index.html or where your camera code.?

Comment: the camera is getting started and then suddenly closes with an alert camera cancelled. Is there anything i should add in config or manifest xml.. ???

Answer (score 4):

This question is is very old, but I got here searching from this problem today. For another users with the same problem, add in `config.xml:`

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="standard"/>
```

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355099/cordova-camera-plugin-selection-cancelled-error).

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, you are missing to set: `encodingType` and `mediaType`.

Check my example:

```
var cameraOptions = {
    quality : quality,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: targetWidth,
    targetHeight: targetHeight,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: saveToPhotoAlbum
};
```

I'd advise you to use JPEG instead of PNG.