# cordova camera plugin. "selection cancelled" error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

hi i create an app with the ionic framework. i installed the cordova-plugin-camera to select and crop a images by my device. but when i try to select an image i receive always the error "selection cancelled"

my code is this

```
var options = {
                    quality: 100,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 500,
                    targetHeight: 500,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
                    correctOrientation: true
                };

                navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageData) {
                    var temp = scope.avatar;
                    scope.avatar = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

                }, function (err) { alert(JSON.stringify(err)); }, options);
```

i receive the error immediately when i call the getPicture function. then before that i select a photo. why this problem? thanks in advance

the strange thing is that until few time ago all work well, i try to install the old version of this plugin but the error is the same. can be a conflict with other plugins? i try also the angular-js version but i have the same error

my plugin list is this

```
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.26.0 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.1 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.1 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.19 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.9 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 11):

solved. i just add this preference in the config.xml file

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="standard"/>
```